# Load typing animation on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this simple typed.js animation that displays text, deletes it and types another string.
I would like to get this animation to load when I click on a navbar link.

```
<div class="container blue circleBehind">
<a href="#" onclick="return show('page1','page2','page3');">TUTORIAL 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return show('page2','page1','page3');">TUTORIAL 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="return show('page3','page1','page2')";>TUTORIAL 3</a>

</div>
<div class="element" id="page3" style="display:none">
</div>


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    Typed.new(".element", {
        strings: ["first sentence", "Second sentence."],
        typeSpeed: 0
    });
});
```

so the first typed sentence: "first sentence" loads as soon as the page loads, I would like it to load when I click on the tutorial 3 button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
function setString(arg){
    var a=arg.innerHTML;
    Typed.new(".element", {
        strings: [a, "This is second"+a],
        typeSpeed: 2
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.7/typed.min.js"></script>
<div class="container blue circleBehind">
 <a href="#" onclick="setString(this);">TUTORIAL 1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setString(this);">TUTORIAL 2</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setString(this);">TUTORIAL 3</a>

</div>
<div class="element" id="page3" >
</div>
```